# Why the positioned DIV is behind the floating DIV

Tags: css

Based on the MDN article "Stacking and float",

> Stacking and float
>
> For floating blocks the stacking order is a bit different. Floating
>   blocks are placed between non-positioned blocks and positioned blocks:
>
> 1. Background and borders of the root element
> 2. Descendant blocks in the normal flow, in order of appearance (in HTML)
> 3. Floating blocks
> 4. Descendant positioned elements, in order of appearance (in HTML)

However, when I try the sample code by myself, I find the DIV#1 is behind the DIV#3. Shouldn't the DIV#1 be in the front the DIV#3?

DIV#1 is positioned element, so it should be rendered after/in front of floating block.

Please check below code or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXID/a1pcoLa0/).

```
<body>
    <br /><br />

    <div id="absdiv1">
        <br /><span class="bold">DIV #1</span>
        <br />position: absolute;
    </div>

    <div id="flodiv1">
        <br /><span class="bold">DIV #2</span>
        <br />float: left;
    </div>

    <div id="flodiv2">
        <br /><span class="bold">DIV #3</span>
        <br />float: right;
    </div>

    <br />

    <div id="normdiv">
        <br /><span class="bold">DIV #4</span>
        <br />no positioning
    </div>

    <div id="absdiv2">
        <br /><span class="bold">DIV #5</span>
        <br />position: absolute;
    </div>
</body>
```

```
div {
    font: 12px Arial;
}

span.bold { font-weight: bold; }

#absdiv1 {
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 10px;
    right: 140px;
    border: 1px dashed #990000;
    background-color: #ffdddd;
    text-align: center;
}

#normdiv {
    /* opacity: 0.7; */
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px dashed #999966;
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

#flodiv1 {
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed #009900;
    background-color: #ccffcc;
    text-align: center;
}

#flodiv2 {
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed #009900;
    background-color: #ccffcc;
    text-align: center;
}

#absdiv2 {
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 130px;
    left: 100px;
    border: 1px dashed #990000;
    background-color: #ffdddd;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's effect of opacity < 1.0. Just comment it:

```
#flodiv2 {
    /*opacity: 0.7;*/
    ...
}
```

and you will see elements in normal order. Elements with opacity < 1.0 establish their own [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Comment: Thanks. So the opacity element has its own stacking context, but I still didn't see what's real rendering order of it. The reference seems not mentioning it. Why does the DIV#1 get rendered behind floating DIV#3?

Comment: Except DIV#4, all other elements have same opacity, should they should be in a same stacking context. So in that stacking context, the floating element should still be rendered before positioned element. Confused.

Answer (score 0):

Concept seems to be working fine. You didn't mention browsers and their version. That might matter if nightly builds are involved. Anyway. Here's the code that works.

```css
body{ background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1); }
div { border: thin solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); width: 60%; }
#floating{ float: right; background-color: rgba(127, 0, 0, .5);}
#descendent-floating{ position: relative; background-color: rgba(0, 127, 0, .5);}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="descendent">descendent</div>
    <div id="floating">floating</div>
    <div id="descendent-floating">descendent-floating</div>
</body>
```

[Here's external link for jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jshacker/vg7qagdb/3/)